# Remove Wrap Text Quotation Mark

Tags: notepad++, line-breaks, carriage-return, quotation-marks

I have a csv file which I am attempting to edit and I notice that there is a line break with text encased in quotation marks. The break causes a portion of text to appear on a new line. See **Current State** (below)

I am attempting to remove the break and quotation marks so that the text that is broken can appear in one line. See **EndState** for what is wanted.

I am new to Notepad++ and not sure if there is a RegEx expression to complete this or a line operation that might help. Any insight would be appreciated.

**Current State**

```
123|12345678910|Harry|Potter?PotterHead|07/31/1980|Test|Test|Project-Test-20240206|Project-Test-20240206|"Return all Information
All information must be returned"|01/01/2024|01/02/2024
```

**EndState**

```
123|12345678910|Harry|Potter?PotterHead|07/31/1980|Test|Test|Project-Test-20240206|Project-Test-20240206|Return all Information All information must be returned|01/01/2024|01/02/2024
```

Answer (score 0):

Replacing `\|"([^"\r\n]*)\R([^"\r\n]*)"\|` with `|\1 \2|` should work.

Explanation

```
\|           Vertical bar, need escaping
"            Itself
(            Capture group 1, containing:
[^"\r\n]*       Zero or more characters that are not quotes or CR or LF
)            End capture group
\R           Any sort of newline
([^"\r\n]*)  Another capture group, number 2
"\|          Quotes and vertical bar
```

The replacement string inserts the vertical bars and the two capture groups, it omits the two double-quotes. There is a space in the replacement to replace the newline sequence.